# Why $S_m\times \ell^2$ cannot be homeomorphic to the $1$-shere of $\ell^2$?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

Let $m\in \mathbb{N}^*$ be a fixed number, and set 
$$S_m:=\{y\in \mathbb{C}^m; \|y\|=1\}$$

> Consider the  $\ell^2$ complex Hilbert space. I want to show that $S_m\times \ell^2$ cannot be homeomorphic to 
>   $$
> S(0,1)=\left\{ x=(x_n)_n\subset \ell^2\ :\ \sum_{n=1}^\infty |x_n|^2=1\right\}.$$

Comment: $S(0,1)$ can be contracted to a point. $S_m\times \ell^2$, on the other hand, can't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To provide the carrying out of deyore's comment:

As a map $S(0,1)\to S(0,1)$ the left shift
$$\sum_k x_k e_k\mapsto \sum_k x_k e_k$$
is homotopic to identity. If you compose this homotopy with:
$$h_t\left(\sum_kx_k e_{k+1}\right)= \sqrt{t}\, e_1+\sqrt{1-t}\sum_k x_k e_{k+1}$$
you will contract to the point $e_1$.

The problem is to show this left shift is homotopic to identity, here you need to see that for all $t$ the map $(1-t)\Bbb1 +tL$ has zero kernel, where $L$ is the left shift. Then the map $x\mapsto \frac{(1-t)x+t Lx}{\|(1-t)x+tLx\|}$ is a homotopy on $S(0,1)$ between the identity and left shift.

Specifically suppose you have a $t$ and an $\sum_k x_ke_k\in \ell^2$ so that

$$[(1-t)\Bbb1+tL]\sum_k x_k e_k =0= \sum_k [(1-t)x_k+tx_{k-1}]e_k$$
Where we define $x_{-1}=0$. Assume $t\neq1$, then the $k=0$ part implies $x_0=0$, plug this into $k=1$ to retrieve $x_1=0$ and so on. Thus the kernel of this map is $0$.

Comment: I think you have only shown in your answer that $S(0,1)$ is simply connected. However why $S_m×ℓ^2$ is not simply connected?Thank you.

Comment: What I have shown is that $S(0,1)$ is _contractible_, a far stronger statement than simply connected. On the other hand $S_m\times\ell^2$ has the homotopy type of a $2m$-sphere, which is not contractible.

Comment: Please why $S_m \times l^2$ is not contractible? I don't understand why $S_m \times l^2$ has the homotopy type of $2m$-spere? According to the following link ''Spheres of any finite dimension are not contractible.''  https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contractible_space

Comment: $\ell^2$ is a vector space and as such contractible. If this is not obvious to you, you need to stop and think about it, understanding why obvious things are obvious is the first hurdle in learning a branch of mathematics. Because $\ell^2$ is contractible you find that $S_m\times \ell^2$ is homotopic to $S^m\times\{pt.\}$, ie to $S_m$. $S_m$ is the unit sphere in $\Bbb C^m$, which is the same as the unit sphere in $\Bbb R^{2m}$. There are many proofs that spheres are not contractible, the simplest use homology but also analytic proofs are possible.

Comment: Thank you very much for the details. Could you please give me a name of a  goog reference in order to understand very well this things